# ASP MVC knockout json nested foreach data binding

Tags: c#, json, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, data-binding

Sorry if this particular question has been asked already, I have been through countless similar questions but none that seem to relate with my problem.

I am fairly new to MVC Web API's and working with JavaScript/knockout.

View model script - QuestionItems.js

```
var SectionModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.SectionName = ko.observable(data.SectionName);
    self.SectionNumber = ko.observable(data.SectionNumber);

    self.Questions = ko.observableArray();

};

var questionnaireViewModel = function () {

    self.sections = ko.observableArray();
    self.error = ko.observable();

    var itemsUri = '/api/QuestionnaireItems/';
    var sectionsUri = '/api/QuestionnaireSections/';

    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        self.error('');
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }

    function getAllQuestions() {
        ajaxHelper(itemsUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            for (var s = 0; s < self.sections.length; s++) {
                // find all the questions for this section
                var sectionQuestions = data.filter(function (item) {
                    return item.SectionName == self.sections[s].SectionName;
                });
                // add the questions to each section
                self.sections.Questions(sectionQuestions);
            }
        });
    }

    function getAllSections() {
        ajaxHelper(sectionsUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            // map each data item to a SectionModel and store that in your main viewModel
            var sectionsTemp = data.map(function (item) {
                return new SectionModel(item);
            });
            self.sections(sectionsTemp);
        });
    }

    getAllSections();
    getAllQuestions();

};

ko.applyBindings(questionnaireViewModel);
```

And my view - Index.cshtml

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/QuestionItems")
}

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">SQA</h1>
    <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: sections">
        <li>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div><strong data-bind="text: SectionNumber"></strong>. <strong data-bind="text: SectionName"></strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul data-bind="foreach: Questions">
                        <li>
                            <span data-bind="text: QuestionNumber"></span>. <span data-bind="text: QuestionName"></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the database I have a QuestionnaireItems table which stores all question details and a foreign key to the sections table to retrieve each questions related section  :

[QuestionnaireItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5c33.png)

And a QuestionnaireSections table which holds each sections name and order number :

[QuestionnaireSections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JFVI.png)

I have managed to get the sections displaying, however the questions are not. If I pull through just the questions without matching them to their correct sections they display. I'm assuming this is a problem with the way the condition is set up but I am at a complete loss as to how I can fix this.

I have also tested the controllers in Postman and all the correct data is pulling through.

QuestionItemList.cs (DTO):

```
public class QuestionItemList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SectionNumber { get; set; }

    public string SectionName { get; set; }

    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }

    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
}
```

SectionItemList.cs (DTO)

```
public class SectionItemList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SectionNumber { get; set; }

    public string SectionName { get; set; }
}
```

QuestionnaireItemsController:

```
    public class QuestionnaireItemsController : ApiController
    {
        private SQAContext db = new SQAContext();

        // GET: api/QuestionnaireItems
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<QuestionItemList> GetItems()
        {
            var items = from a in db.QuestionnaireItems
                        select new QuestionItemList()
                        {
                            Id = a.PID,
                            SectionNumber = a.QuestionnaireSection.Number,
                            SectionName = a.QuestionnaireSection.Name,
                            QuestionNumber = a.Number,
                            QuestionName = a.Name
                        };

            return items;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool QuestionnaireItemExists(int id)
        {
            return db.QuestionnaireItems.Count(e => e.PID == id) > 0;
        }
    }
```

QuestionnaireSectionsController:

```
public class QuestionnaireSectionsController : ApiController
{
    private SQAContext db = new SQAContext();

    // GET: api/QuestionnaireSections
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<SectionItemList> GetSectionItems()
    {
        var items = from a in db.QuestionnaireSections
                    select new SectionItemList()
                    {
                        Id = a.PID,
                        SectionNumber = a.Number,
                        SectionName = a.Name
                    };

        return items;
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool QuestionnaireSectionExists(int id)
    {
        return db.QuestionnaireSections.Count(e => e.PID == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you seem to use traditional `for` , under it you should use index based assigning like `self.sections[s].Questions(sectionQuestions);` . that should fix the troubles .

Comment: so whats the issue can you brief it here .

Comment: The list of sections are displaying, but the questions under each section are not.

Comment: yes it wont @karyn . this piece of code is wrong as there is no `[s]` `self.sections.Questions(sectionQuestions);` . try doing as instructed in my top comment & let us know

Comment: You might want to consider adding a new Web API endpoint (you can leave the others, as they may be viable for other use cases) that loads the  section and questions as a single bundle of data instead of making two async calls and doing the combining work on the client. The server-side code will probably be easier for you to work with since you are new to JavaScript. This will also simplify your JavaScript code into one AJAX call. I would also recommend creating a QuestionModel on the client-side that can be mapped from the data.Questions sent to the SectionModel.

Comment: @supercool yeah I noticed the [s] was missing straight after I posted this question - was from playing around and trying to figure it out - added it back in but makes no change.

Comment: @KarlAnderson my QuestionnaireItems API does collect all this data as a bundle : [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "SectionNumber": 1,
    "SectionName": "Business Management Systems",
    "QuestionNumber": 1,
    "QuestionName": "Does your business operate a Quality Management system?"
  }...... I originally only binded this in the script but again they were not linked.. Would it be better to rather go back to only calling that 1 APIs data and work off from there?

Comment: @Karyn - that is what I what I would do, it will simplify the logic for building up your model (section) and sub-models (questions within each section).

Comment: @KarlAnderson Omg I feel so dumb. I was making the typical beginner mistake of over complicating things! I've now done a simple AJAX call to just the QuestionnaireItems data, binded that to one observableArray and everything works correctly now! Thanks so much!!

Comment: you can post it as an answer so the question is visibly closed :)

Comment: @Karyn - awesome, glad you got it working on your own. Good luck to you.